# Structure of large list

Tags: r, list, httr

Here's a reproducible example:

```
a <- list(list(LETTERS[1:3],LETTERS[1:3]),list(LETTERS[4:6]))
a
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "D" "E" "F"
```

Can someone explain the logic behind the list numbering?

I have a very large list of lists...(223 deep), example 5 deep:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
list()

[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]]
Response [https://api.livechatinc.com/v2/chats?/date_from=2014-03-22&page=1]
Date: 2015-03-20 15:41
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 166 kB
```

down to:

```
[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
Response [https://api.livechatinc.com/v2/chats?/date_from=2014-03-22&page=5]
Date: 2015-03-20 15:41
Status: 200
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Size: 133 kB
```

And wish to extract content using httr's content function.  Using lapply returns: Error: is.response(x) is not TRUE

The only way I know to access each is to call each list directly:

```
content(listName[[1]][[2]][[1]])
```

Any suggestions how I can call the function `content` on each one?

I tried content within `rapply` and also `unlist`, then content with no change in error message.

Comment: Maybe `rapply` would be more useful...?

Comment: Or perhaps use `unlist`?

Comment: put a small reproducible example, how your list is structured? All leaves are lists?

Comment: How did you end up with this structure? Seems like if you have code that's creating this, maybe you can simplify that so as to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example structure that sounds sort of like yours:

```
library("httr")
u <- "http://www.google.com"
g <- GET(u)
a <- list()
a[[1]] <- g
a[[2]] <- list(g, g)
a[[3]] <- list(g, list(g))
a[[4]] <- list(list(g, list(list(g, g))))
str(a, 1)
# List of 4
#  $ :List of 9
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "response"
#  $ :List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#  $ :List of 1
```

You can write a function that either extracts the contents of the request or, if inapplicable, tries to recursively extract contents from nodes lower on the list tree. Then `lapply` that function to your list:

```
extract <- function(x) {
    if(inherits(x, "response")) {
        return(content(x))
    } else if(length(x)){
        lapply(x, extract) # apply `extract` recursively
    }
}

out <- unlist(lapply(a, extract))
```

Result is a list of extracted contents:

```
str(out)
# List of 8
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
#  $ :Classes 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'HTMLInternalDocument', 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr>
```

Comment: Looks promising - it didn't work on first pass but I'll give it another go and feedback (taking a week off first).   Cheers.

Comment: I didn't end up using this as I realised that a nested for loop would get my results but I figure this Q & A is worth keeping as a decent example.